# PHP Error as PEAR not being found by script

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to run a PHP script and I am getting an error regarding PEAR script. I believe I have done everything required but I am still get this error:

[image]

I have included the link to PEAR (as the error suggests to do), as follows:

[image]

Also the file structure of my PHP setup with PEAR is like this

[image]

And I have the following path link in my php.ini file

[image]

This may be something quite easy as I am not a PHP developer, so any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You cannot `require` a directory, or multiple directories. You only `require` one file at a time.

Comment: Thanks, but then why is the error saying `(include_path='.;C\:PHP7\PEAR')`

Comment: PHP will look in that list of directories by default if you require relative paths. For example, if you require `foo.php`, it will look in the current directory first, and `C:\PHP7\PEAR` second.

Comment: The original script had the line `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` is this something to do with it? I'm not quite sure how to fix this

Comment: The original script assumed you were using composer. You should probably be using composer instead of manually making changes in these files